# Can I use cl_context to compare OpenCL contexts?

Tags: opencl

If I have two `cl_context`s `c1` and `c2`, can I equality compare them (`c1 == c2`) to figure out if they represent different contexts? In particular:

- Is it guaranteed that if `c1 == c2`, they represent the same context?
- Is it guaranteed that if `c1 != c2`, they represent different contexts?

Any references to relevant documentation is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification doesn't explicitly state this, but I don't see how your first test could possibly be false. How would the runtime know which of the 2 contexts is meant if they have the same handle/pointer value? The C type system does not allow for types which are `==`-comparable but aren't actually equal if `==` evaluates to true. (In C++, operator overloading would make this possible of course.)

For the second test, I'd be curious to know from where you'd be expecting to obtain different `cl_context` handles to the same context? For functions such as `clGetCommandQueueInfo(queue, CL_QUEUE_CONTEXT, …)`, the specification is probably clear enough: "Return the context specified when the command-queue is created." I don't think that can be interpreted as "Can return a different handle to the same context than the one that was specified when the command-queue was created." So I don't see under what circumstances you might end up with 2 different handles to the same context.

You *don't* ask, "could 2 calls to `clCreateContext()` with identical arguments return the same context?" - This is related to your first question but slightly different. As far as I'm aware, contexts are stateless from an API perspective (aside from reference count, which is opaque - you must balance releases with retains or behaviour is undefined), and the specification doesn't state that the context will be unique, so I suppose some implementations might choose to return the same context twice in such a case. (It seems unlikely though, as the question would be: why?) If this is a concern, make sure to pass unique `user_data` pointers to each of your `clCreateContext()` calls.

Finally, I don't actually see anywhere in the specification that defines whether `cl_context` be comparable with `==` in the first place. However, the `clCreateContext` family of functions may return `NULL` in case of an error, which implies that `cl_context` can't really be anything other than a `typedef` for a pointer type. Additionally, the official C++ wrapper, `cl2.hpp`, defines `==` and `!=` operators on the wrapper classes which compare the underlying C handles for the OpenCL objects with `==` and `!=`.

So I think it's pretty safe to say that both conditions hold.

Comment: This matches my intuition. Thanks for sharing your thoughts on it! As for why I think `cl_context` is comparable, this page specifies what you say, that they are indeed `typedef`s for pointers:  https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/abstractDataTypes.html

Comment: "As far as I'm aware, contexts are stateless from an API perspective" - i'm not sure what you mean by "API perspective", but i wouldn't count on OpenCL 1.2 contexts being stateless. E.g. Nvidia launches threads internally on clCreateContexts. Stateless context is even less likely with OpenCL 2.0 because of SVM - in particular, clSVMAlloc returns a simple pointer, and if the implementation wants to check it in clSVMFree, it would likely keep some per-context data structure with all allocated SVM pointers. Just FYI :)

Comment: @mogu Obviously there's some internal state involved, but the API behaves as if there wasn't. There aren't any mutable properties that can be set. If 2 contexts were actually implemented as one shared context, there's no well-defined way for the programmer to tell the difference. Objects created in the one context would work with objects from the other, but this is undefined behaviour as far as the standard goes, so you shouldn't be attempting it in the first place.